# Installing PHP dependencies

Tags: yum, rpm

While trying to install php-mysql package, I get the following error.
It was working fine with php-5.1.6-27.el5 and mysql 5.0 version. After MySQL upgrade, certain PHP pages had issues and I had to upgrade to PHP 5.3 But it did not resolve the issue.

```
# yum install php-mysql  --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.2-3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.2.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-mysql-5.3.2-3.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.2-3.x86_64 (base)
php-mysql-5.3.2-3.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.2-3.x86_64 (base)

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.2.x86_64 from base
    php-mysql-5.3.2-3.x86_64 from base
```

Which steps are needed to complete this installation process?

Comment: How did you do the mysql and php upgrades?  Via RPM, and if so, from what repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using repositories such as webtactic should be a last resort. They normally are run by one person and even assuming that there are no other problems with the package if that person gets busy with other tasks you can easily be vulnerable to an attack that is unpatched. CentOS/RHEL 5.6 added php53 as an official package along side the existing php version.

You will need to remove your existing php stuff before adding the new version. I have had some problems with not everything being avalible for php53 so do a quick check of what is installed first. Then compare that to what is avalible.

Check what is installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep php*
```

Check what is avalible:

```
yum search php53
```

If everything that you have installed for php is available in the php53 version uninstall what you have and then reinstall the new versions.

Remove:

```
yum remove php*
```

Install the new versions:

```
yum install php53 php53-devel php53-mysql ...
```

As a system administrator I would be MUCH more comfortable with these versions. Although I must admit they lack some of the plugins such as APC.

Comment: Give IUS a try: http://iuscommunity.org/  It's run by Rackspace, so it's a bit more stable then a repo run by one person.

Answer (score 0):

What repositories do you have enabled?  Try disabling all of the repositories except the base/default ones.

Comment: That won't help because PHP 5.3 isn't in the base repository.

Comment: It is for RHEL 6 derivatives.  I don't see him ever indicating what OS he is running.

Comment: I stand corrected (although php-5.1.6-27.el5 must be a clue).

Answer (score 0):

I went through this just yesterday and only got it sorted (on a 32 bit system) after running

`yum --enablerepo=webtatic update php*`

In case you don't have it, the webtatic.repo file contains

```
[webtatic]
name=Webtatic Repository $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy
```